# Using pass on a non necessary else statement

Tags: python, pep8

Based on PEP8 documentation, I was not able to find any reference regarding if I should use `pass` for aesthetic reasons on code. Based on the example below, should I keep those `else` or can I erase them?  Until now, the main reason I'm keeping it is based on the mantra "Explicit is better than implicit."

```
if fields:
    for i in foo:
        if i == 'something':
            print "something"
        else:
            pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Don't confuse explicit and redundant.

Comment: or you do `for i in filter(lambda i: i == 'something', foo)`, then you don't even need to think about an `else`.

Comment: In general, and regardless of the programming language, code that does nothing should be removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can/should remove them because they do nothing.

The Python community teaches "explicit is better than implicit" as long as the explicit code does something useful.  Those `else: pass`'s however contribute nothing positive to the code.  Instead, all they do is pointlessly consume two lines each.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely remove those as there's no point in keeping code around that serves no purpose:

```
if fields:
    for i in foo:
        if i == 'something':
            print "something"
```

Answer (score 3):

An else pass is dead code, you should remove it, as it adds unnecessary noise to the code and anyway the code will be clearer and easier to understand without it.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of few cases where *pass* may be useful - the latter two are temporarily stubs:

- When you want to do ignore an acceptable exception
- When you need to insert a breakpoint at the end of function when debugging.
- As a filler in a function whose implementation you want to postpone

I cannot imagine any other case where I will use *pass*

**EDIT:**

In some cases, when implementing *if*-*elif*-*else* chain, and you have some common condition that requires no action - along with rare conditions that do require specific actions - for the sake of execution efficiency, you may use *pass* after the first *if*:

```
if <some common condition>:
    pass
elif <rare condition>:
    <do something>
elif <another rare condition>:
    <do something else>
else:
   <do another stuff>
```

Comment: How is it more efficient to use `pass` in this case?

Comment: @LS, checking each condition takes time - most probably nanoseconds. Usually it's negligible - after all, you don't usually write RT implementation in Python :). However, if either more rare conditions entail turning to some slow APIs, e.g. - DB, Web services, or you get into the chain frequently - then advantage of skipping the whole chain may be beneficial.

Comment: It would be simpler to negate the logic with `not`, changing the first three lines into these two: `if not <some common condition>:`, `if <rare condition>:`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about ***else*** is that they are not just a part of the if statements; it appears in ***try*** statements and ***for*** loops too. You don't see *else* being used (in this context) in those areas, do you?

```
try:
    raw_input("say my name")
except:
    print "Heisenberg"
# Meh, this is not needed.
else:
    pass
```

If we are looping over something and checking for some condition (with the *if*), then an *else* would add unnecessary lines.

Here's a loop for finding a folder:

```
for path in pathlist
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        print "Found a folder, yay!"
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Clearly, *else* is executed in every loop and is pointless. This could be avoided as implied in the **PEP 8** itself:

> ***But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.
>   Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate
>   to ask! 
> When applying the guideline would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows this PEP.***