# Should I always complete all conditions even if some are empty?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Should I always complete all possible conditions even if some of them I don't have any action to move, especially for the non-pure functions

Quick example:

```
def add_somenumber(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        lst.append(1)
    elif len(lst) <= 5:
        lst.append(5)
    else:
        pass
```

Or it could be:

```
def add_somenumber(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 10:
        lst.append(0)
    elif 10 < len(lst) < 20:
        pass
    else:
        lst.append(1)
```

And the above can be written as:

```
def add_somenumber(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 10:
        lst.append(0)
    elif len(lst) >= 20:
        lst.append(1)
```

The function itself has no meaning, but in this situation, should I skip the `else` part?

The reason is that if I only have `if` and `elif` it might lead to the question if I considered all conditions. But then the `else` part seems quite useless.

Comment: That's what comments are for, if you need to emphasize that you deliberately took no action: `# Do nothing if len(lst) > 5`

Comment: IMO there is zero reason to have ```else:  pass```. Depending on consistency it may be required, but if you're really worried about whether or not you've covered all the necessary cases-- that's what unit testing is for.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859998/using-pass-on-a-non-necessary-else-statement

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I think using comments can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right answer here, it's merely a question of style.

However, when I encounter a situation like this (a block of code with no meaning), I usually just whack it. The fact that the block is there insinuates to your code's maintainers (or your future self) that it has some purpose and is unnecessarily confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, the else condition is doing nothing at all, so it doesn't make sense to have it.

But you also ask about wondering if you've considered all situations. When writing programs that need to be more robust, it is always good practice to have a catch for unconsidered events, either through logging or raising an exception. In this case, you would implement it with an else to check when the other two conditions were not evaluated  to True.

Example:

```
def add_somenumber(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        lst.append(1)
    elif len(lst) <= 5:
        lst.append(5)
    else:
        raise Exception('lst had an unexpected length')
```

or

```
def add_somenumber(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        lst.append(1)
    elif len(lst) <= 5:
        lst.append(5)
    else:
        print('lst had an unexpected length') # or you can log this
```

Comment: That's a new idea, but this will terminate the script running with an Error, and I really don't need an error here to stop me, I just want it to skip.

Comment: Then a log message would be the best option